# To extract substring from a given string in google sheets using RegexExtract

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 10k records in a format like(in Google sheets) :

1. Status Updated From A| **(Stage 2A)** to Follow |  Follow-up by.
2. Status Updated | Follow-up to Cx | Not responding **(Stage 1A)** by Test
3. Status Updated From User Activity Received to X| All Ok **(Stage 7)** by John.Doe

and so on records are there I want to extract the **Stage Name**, i.e from 1st record want to extract **Stage 2A**, Similarly from the second record  want to extract **Stage 1A** and so on in separate column:

what I am trying is = RegexExtract(J, "Stage") where J is the column where I have this record value,
the thing I that Stage is fixed but serial no 1A, 1B,2A, etc are dynamic so how can I extract the complete Stage name like **Stage 1A** in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\(Stage (.+?)\)")
```

The pattern captures the stage name in `(.+?)`.  Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ShDPDc/1) showing that the pattern is working.